# How to install Criterion to specific folder?

Tags: makefile, cmake, installation

I have Criterion framework (https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion), I want to build it from source and install to specific directory so headers of criterion should be located in
            /usr/include/

and libraries libcriterion.so in /usr/lib64 folder
I use this command to build and install:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . 
make install
```

it installs .so files to /usr/local/ folder, bash command find / -name "*criterion*" shows this:

```
/usr/local/lib/libcriterion.so
/usr/local/lib/libcriterion.so.3
/usr/local/lib/libcriterion.so.3.1.0
/usr/local/share/pkgconfig/criterion.pc
/usr/local/include/criterion
/usr/local/include/criterion/criterion.h
```

How can I fix my command so that after installation libcriterion.so was located in /usr/lib64 directory ?

Comment: For choose another installation prefix, pass `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr` option for `cmake`. Note, that you cannot change library installation subdirectory `lib/` to `lib64/`, as `lib` is *hardcoded* into the project.

Comment: *Why* do you want to install to `/usr/include` instead of `/usr/local/include`?  The former should be reserved for system include files on almost any system.

Answer (score 1):

Using CMake command line options does not allow changing the library install location as requested. You could change use the `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=...` option, but that would affect the include location, as well.

However, since you have access to the source code, you could simply modify the `CMakeLists.txt` file and set the library install location by adding a command like this:

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib64
)
```

For further details, I may link to the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html#targets).

---

By the way: There is no need to create the build directory explicitly, your script could look like this

```
cmake -H. -Bbuild
cmake --build build
cmake --build build --target install
```